# Black screen after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, resolution

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a partition along with Windows XP, but when I start Ubuntu I only get a black screen. I repeated the installation 3 times successfully, but my screen remains black. Can someone help me?